# Get the Root of a cNFT

Tags: cnft, umi, das

I want to use the compressed NFT SDK from Tensor to create and delist NFTs.

Using the DAS API I would like to know how I can get the `root`.

Fetching using `fetchMerkleTree` from `umi` I get the changeLogs and I do not know how to proceed from here.

```
    const merkleTreeAccount = await fetchMerkleTree(umi, merkleTree)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the root of your fetched Merkle Tree account using the `getCurrentRoot` helper function like so:

```
const merkleTreeAccount = await fetchMerkleTree(umi, merkleTree);
const root = getCurrentRoot(merkleTreeAccount.tree)
```